# C: Var and Function have same name -- a bug of ld?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

In my project (https://github.com/zzt93/os-lab1), I encounter that a global variable has the same name with a function, but compile it produce on error or warning, which cause a bug.

A simple program which can almost reproduce this problem:

```
 //a.c
 struct {
     int t;
     int *s;
 } empty, full;

 int main(){
     printf("full is at %p", &full);
     printf("empty is at %p", &empty);
     empty.t = 1;
     return 0;
 }


 //b.c
 int empty() {
     return 1;
 }
```

Compiling them use `gcc -o res.out -Wall -g -Wextra a.c b.c`
will just produce some warning like this (**notice: in my project, it even produce no error**):

> /usr/bin/ld: Warning: alignment 1 of symbol `empty` in /tmp/ccq70SCM.o is smaller than 16 in /tmp/ccVCOeWq.o
>
> /usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `empty` changed from 16 in /tmp/ccVCOeWq.o to 11 in /tmp/ccq70SCM.o
>
> /usr/bin/ld: Warning: type of symbol `empty` changed from 1 to 2 in /tmp/ccq70SCM.o

it seems it take `struct empty` and `function empty` as the same one.

Decompile it, you can clearly see that linker link the address of `function empty` rather than that `struct empty`.So try running `res.out` will cause segment fault.

```
  40054e:   be 73 05 40 00          mov    $0x400573,%esi
  400553:   bf 12 06 40 00          mov    $0x400612,%edi
  400558:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40055d:   e8 ae fe ff ff          callq  400410 <printf@plt>
  400562:   c7 05 07 00 00 00 01    movl   $0x1,0x7(%rip)            # 400573 <empty>
  400569:   00 00 00 
  40056c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400571:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400572:   c3                      retq   

0000000000400573 <empty>:
  400573:   55                      push   %rbp
  400574:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400577:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  40057c:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  40057d:   c3                      retq   
  40057e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

### Question:

Why linker choose function rather than that struct? Am i right to think it as a bug?

why add a static for the declaration of struct can prevent this error? -- I understand that `static` make the variable invisible outside this file, but notice **I add static to `struct empty` not `function empty`** solving the problem.

**Edit:**:
And strange enough, in the symbol table of res.out, there is only one `empty`

```
Name                  Value           Class        Type         Size             Line  Section
empty               |0000000000400573|   T  |              FUNC|000000000000000b|     |.text
```

I am using

> gcc version 4.9.2

Answer (score 4):

Adding `static` prevents the error because `static`, when applied to functions or global variables, makes the symbol not be exported to the linker - in simple words, it makes it "private" to that file.

If you don't use `static`, the linker will see both definitions, but the types don't match. However, since compilation is applied file by file, the linker has no way to *know* the correct type of a variable - it must trust that you did your job and didn't lie.

This is why header files are important - it makes sure that types match in different files.

Comment: Sorry to not so clear, I am adding static to that struct rather than that function and you seems misunderstand it. By the way, do you mean we should always import headers even I don't need it?!! I think always to add static is good solution rather than a header.

Comment: From the symbol table, we can see that linker should tell the difference between `FUNC` and `OBJECT`.